# Socket connect successful even for wrong IP

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've written a simple kernel module to connect to a server running on 'ip'. Although, I change ip to wrong value it gives me succes. Here's the code,

```
memset(&kthread->addr_send, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
kthread->addr_send.sin_family = AF_INET;
kthread->addr_send.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
kthread->addr_send.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
if ( (err = kthread->sock_send->ops->connect(kthread->sock_send, (struct sockaddr *)&kthread->addr_send, sizeof(struct sockaddr), 0) ) < 0 ) {
      printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": Could not connect to socket, error = %d\n", -err);
      goto again;
    }

printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": Connection Success to %s \n", ip);
```

inet_addr() is written by me and it gives perfect output. What seems to be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you saved and re-compiled after changing the ip address?

Comment: ip is changed runtime. It is received from another module. I checked and it is received correctly.

Comment: Do you disconnect from the server between changes?

Comment: Yes. The socket is released at the end and created again, before changing 'ip'.

Comment: Well, in that case, you'll probably need to trace the 'ip' variable. I'm not convinced you're ready to be working on sockets anyways, given that you're still using `goto`

Comment: And with that, I'm out.